# Batch: list available hard drives

Tags: batch-file, cmd, volume, wmic

I need to list all available hard drives using batch. I've tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list= "
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption') do (
  set "list=!list!%%a"
)
choice /c %list% /m "Enter drive "
set "disk=!list:~%errorlevel%,1!:"
echo you chose %disk%
```

But it gives me the error:

```
3 - Invalid alias verb.
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Value expected for '/c'.
Type "CHOICE /?" for usage.
you chose :
```

Comment: You need to escape the `=` in `drivetype=3 `; ie `drivetype^=3`

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted in the comment by Magoo was correct !

The `=` symbol in `drivetype=3` needs to be escaped in order for the `wmic` command to work correctly.

***Edit :*** thanks to **aschipfl**

The `=` sign is a token separator just like space or tab; in the `for /F` context it becomes replaced by a space; to prevent that, it must be escaped like `^=`

You can escape the `=` sign by using the caret `(^)` symbol before it, like this: `drivetype^=3`

---

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "list="
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=3 get caption') do (
  set "list=!list!%%a "
)
choice /c "%list: =" /m "Enter drive "
set "disk=%%list:~%errorlevel%,1%%"
echo you chose %disk% 
pause
```

Comment: No, Hackoo, the `=`-sign is not (mis-)interpreted as variable assignment! It's a token separator – just like space or tab; in the `for /F` context it becomes replaced by a space; to prevent that, it must be escaped like `^=`…

Comment: For completeness: Other ways to "handle" it: `... in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption') ...` (quoting as part of the `wmic` syntax), `... in ('"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption"') ...`  (quoting as part of the `for` syntax). *Not*  possible: `... in ('"wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get caption"') ...` (using both methods - technically, the `=` is *outside* the quoted strings here and again needs to be escaped: `...in ('"wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype^=3" get caption"') ...`